# fill-paragraph does not honor fill-column

Tags: fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode, fill-column

<kbd>C-h v</kbd> `fill-column` gives me 80.

Pasting the lorem ipsum text in `*scratch*` (lines longer than 80) then going <kbd>M-x</kbd> `fill-paragraph` fills around column 66.

The same in `c-mode`. In this mode, comment wraps seem to work, but not raw text outside code.

If I switch to `text-mode`, filling paragraphs work as I expect (column 80).

What makes it fail in `*scratch*` and in `c-mode`?

Comment: It should also work in fundamental mode. Only not in program modes

Comment: @Rusi it is possible that my scratch wasn't in fundamental mode anymore. Why shouldn't it work in program modes?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Surely the notion of paragraph doesn't make much sense for program modes. But why it works with some default value of fill-column (instead of just not having that key bound)... Dunno. I'd say it's a bug

Answer (score 2):

Filling is a general facility which can depend on more than just the `fill-column` variable, however the first thing to test is simply that you're checking the `fill-column` value for the correct buffer -- it can have a different value in each buffer; so if you typed <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> from some other buffer, you might see the wrong value.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `fill-paragraph` tells us that its behaviour depends on the value of the `fill-paragraph-function` variable, which in turn is described thus:

> ```
> Mode-specific function to fill a paragraph, or nil if there is none.
> If the function returns nil, then `fill-paragraph' does its normal work.
> A value of t means explicitly "do nothing special".
> Note: This only affects `fill-paragraph' and not `fill-region'
> nor `auto-fill-mode', so it is often better to use some other hook,
> such as `fill-forward-paragraph-function'.
> ```

In `*scratch*` <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `fill-paragraph-function` leads us to:

> ```
> lisp-fill-paragraph is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `lisp-mode.el'.
>
> (lisp-fill-paragraph &optional JUSTIFY)
>
> Like M-q, but handle Emacs Lisp comments and docstrings.
> If any of the current line is a comment, fill the comment or the
> paragraph of it that point is in, preserving the comment's indentation
> and initial semicolons.
> ```

Similarly, in `c-mode` buffers we're using the function `c-fill-paragraph` (which see).

As you might imagine, many of the mode-specific functions use alternative variables with `fill-column` in their name, so this ought to show you some illuminating things as well:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `fill-column` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: To expand slightly on this, `lisp-fill-paragraph` temporarily binds `fill-column` to `emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` if that is set to an integer.  It's 65 by default.  Customizing it to `nil` would use the default value of `fill-column`